# Netty class not found exception while executing JAR

Tags: java, jar, netty

I've made JAR file from a project I made, however when I try to execute it, it gives:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/netty/channel/socket/ServerSocketChannelFactory
at org.ddosdefense.httpfilter.HTTPInterceptor.main(HTTPInterceptor.java:66)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.ServerSocketChannelFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 1 more
```

Inside the jar file all the libraries are present.
In the .classpath file the netty jar library is present:

```
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="ddos2_lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar"/>
```

When I execute the project in eclipse it works perfectly. Anyone has an idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you don't have the jar packaged into the jar you produce or missed to specify the netty jar via the -cp option.

Comment: Firstly, the JAR contains the netty JAR, I've tried to do the following:
`java -cp DDoSTool.jar org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.ServerSocketChannelFactory`
However it did not work for following reasons, because it is not the main class.
Any other ideas?